# How to use positional arguments in `__init__` while using `singledispatchmethod`

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to different ways to instantiate `Service` class. That's means some times I have to pass `(a: str, b: str)` and sometimes `(d: dict)`. To do so, I am using `singledispatchmethod` from `functools` to have two ways to define `__init__` method. See the code below:

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class Service:
    
    @singledispatchmethod
    def __init__(self, d: dict):
        self.a = d.get('a')
        self.b = d.get('b')
        
    @__init__.register
    def _(self, a: str, b: str):
        d = {"a": a, "b": b}
        self.__init__(d)
```

when I instantiate using non positional arguments it works as expected. But with positional argument:

```
s = Service(d={"a":1, "b": 2})
```

it raises an error `tuple index out of range`, this is the return traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/*/*/*/scratch_3.py", line 16, in <module>
    s = Service(d={"a":1, "b": 2})
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 911, in _method
    method = self.dispatcher.dispatch(args[0].__class__)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What change should be done here, to be able to use positional argument?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a common way to have multiple ways to construct an object is to use classmethods as alternate constructors. See [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/support-your-class-users-by-providing-an-alternate-way-of-creating-class-instances-using-class-e2da42241913) and also the stdlib's datetime library for examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use `singledispatchmethod`, then here is one example you can use with `isinstance`.

```
class Service:
    
    def __init__(self, d, b=None):

        if isinstance(d, dict):
            
            self.a = d.get('a')
            self.b = d.get('b')

        elif isinstance(d, str) and isinstance(b, str):

            self.a = d
            self.b = b
```